# Translation of mathematical term

Tags: word-choice, translation

In Italian, we say that something holds "definitivamente" for a sequence if it is true for all the elements of the sequence from a certain starting point on (to the limit if it exists). What is the equivalent in English?

PS Is this question more appropriate on [Math SX](http://math.stackexchange.com) perhaps? If so, I'd be thankful if it were migrated.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate on Math SX. But I believe that what you're looking for is the word [*eventually*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventually_(mathematics)).

Comment: @petershor yes it is :). Converting to an answer would result in acceptance, ending the course of this question, I'd say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the word [*eventually*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventually_(mathematics)).